# Deducing lambdas to std::function<T>

Tags: c++, templates, lambda, std-function

I'm essentially trying to have it so I can create a generic callback from any lamba with captures: `GenericCallback([=]{});`

Using the following class:

```
template<typename T> class GenericCallback : public Callback {
public:
    GenericCallback(const std::function<T>& f) {
        mFunction = f;
    }

    void Call() override {
        mFunction();
    }

    std::function<T> mFunction;
};
```

The problem is it expects me to define the template arguments.  There's no issues doing so in general, but if I use any captures, whether it's using `[=]` or specific arguments, the type becomes impossible for me to shove it into this structure.

My end goal is to simply call these functions at a later time with a specified condition.

A case where this errors:

```
int v = 5;
GenericCallback<void()>([=]{ int x = v; });
```

Comment: Can you provide a *specific example*? I have an idea, but not sure if it will work in that case.

Comment: @Incomputable `GenericCallback([=]{});`

Comment: Well, I wanted something compilable, but nevermind.

Comment: *"the type becomes impossible for me to shove it into this structure."* How so? `GenericCallback<void()>{[=]{}}` works fine.

Comment: @0x499602D2 I'll adjust my question to be more specific about captures.

Comment: What advantage does `GenericCallback` provide over just using `std::function` directly?

Comment: @MilesBudnek I've updated my question.  Essentially, my end goal is to have an array of Callback*'s that I can just execute.  I would be happy using an array of generic/non-typed `std::function` but that of course isn't an option.

Comment: @MikeWeir, it seems like you're looking for type erasure. Your class is not able to do that. In fact, it has the same, or less, capabilities as `std::function`.

Comment: How would you put differently typed `std::function` objects into an array?

Comment: Can you specify what compiler and C++ version you're using?
Clang-5 with C++14 for example seems to work fine:
https://wandbox.org/permlink/D8nGrwsShZcc9uXC

Comment: @MikeWeir, `std::function` can store any callable that is compatible with the signature it's given, so `std::function<void()> a([some_int]{ return some_int; });` is perfectly valid.  So you can just have an array of `std::function<void()>` and store any callable object that takes no parameters in it.

Comment: @ecatmur All examples/answers doesn't satisfy captures, which is my only concern.

Comment: What's the error? https://wandbox.org/permlink/rMuH03rM32WpPOtB works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You misunderstand the whole concept of `std::function<>` and overcomplicated the issue. You can use `std::function<void()>` in this case and bind pretty match anything to it, you need to change type in `<>` only when you need to change calling signature. So

```
class Callback {
public:
    using callback_type = std::function<void()>;

    Callback( callback_type cb ) : m_cb( cb ) {}
    void call() { m_cb(); }

private:
    callback_type m_cb;
};

int main()
{
    int v;
    Callback c( [=]{ int x = v; } );
    c.call();
}
```

would simple work and you do not need template there. You need to change type in `std::function` in this case only if you want `Callback::call()` to pass something to that callback or make it to return something and I doubt you plan to do that.

[live example](https://ideone.com/HmAEsf)

Comment: You're absolutely right.  Thank you for clarifying this for me.